# bring in dependency in live script c# compiler

Tags: c#, reference, assemblies

I am trying to create a form in C#.

Unfortunately, I can not use Visual Studio for this effort.

The program I am using has a live script c# compiler that allow user to write and compile code within the program. I am trying to use

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

but I get the following error

> The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Is there a way to reference `System.Windows.Forms` with out visual studio?

I tried this on a online compiler and got similar results so maybe there is a correlation?

Comment: Are you trying to get a win form to open from a browser application?

Comment: What program are you using to write this code?  This program hopefully has some way to reference other DLLs, or control how the code gets compiled.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: The real question i guess is, for the environment youre in, how to somehow bring in a dependency. I changed the title since the issue applies to all dependencies and would be more useful as a general question along those lines.